# How to create segue from a UIPickerView cell

Tags: ios5, uistoryboardsegue

I created a picker for showing users, from CoreData, but I would like the first option to be to create a user, so that even if there are no users, the picker will be of use.

I am using a storyboard for my program, and I would like to have a segue from that first cell to a new UIView.

I found two related questions that had no answers, so I am thinking there is no simple solution to this one, and if there is a more correct approach that would be great, as it may be that I just create a new button to create the user, but that seems like a bad design.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936130/how-to-use-storyboard-segue-from-a-table-cell-to-self-view-controller-and-others

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936130/how-to-use-storyboard-segue-from-a-table-cell-to-self-view-controller-and-others

Comment: How do you intend to perform the segue? by having that row selected and pushing a button? by pushing an element inside the row? or how?

Comment: @LuisOscar - I would like them to select the row, and have it move to the new view.

Comment: I am confused, i dont see the problem here. Can you just see if your coredata is empty? and if it is programatically create a cell that says "create user..." and use the delegate - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component to check if that row is selected and if it is just present the new viewcontroller?

Comment: @LuisOscar - If there are users created I still want them to be able to create new users.

Comment: then it is much easier, ignore the condition to if its empty and simply set the first row to create new user, the behaviour of uipickerview is very similar to the table view regarding how you load the elements using the delegates.